# monitoring Oracle DB using a Docker Container

Tags: oracle, docker, monitor, nagios

I currently am using an application called Portainer ( https://github.com/portainer ) to monitor Docker containers on different machines. It helps to look at everything that is running from one centralized area.

On another machine, I have an Oracle DB (non-docker) running.

I would like to have some kind of monitoring for the Oracle DB (and the OS there as well) using some kind of Docker container.  I want to incorporate it into Portainer (and monitor the Oracle DB and OS from the centralize area as well).

Is there some kind of Docker image out there that would help to accomplish this?

TIA

## Upate

I found the following items here:

```
=> Docker for Nagios
https://github.com/JasonRivers/Docker-Nagios

=> Docker for Oracle Client
https://github.com/sergeymakinen/docker-oracle-instant-client/blob/master/12.1/Dockerfile

=> The Oracle monitoring plugin for Nagios
https://www.nagios.com/solutions/oracle-monitoring/
PDF: https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/Installing-Oracle-Plugins-in-Nagios-XI.pdf#_ga=2.251862537.1091317236.1512242993-1356949649.1512242993
```

I combined items (1) and (2) into a Docker file and added the code below to the file in order to access the ability to monitor Oracle:

```
ENV PLUGIN_URL "http://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/packages/check_oracle_health-1.7.3.tar.gz"
ENV PLUGIN_VER 1.7.3

RUN set -x \
    && cd /tmp \
    && wget http://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/packages/check_oracle_health-1.7.3.tar.gz \
    && tar xvf check_oracle_health-1.7.3.tar.gz \
    && cd check_oracle_health-1.7.3 \
    && ./configure \
    && make all \
    && make install \
    && mkdir /var/tmp/check_oracle_health \
    && chown -R nagios /var/tmp/check_oracle_health
```

I did not get the commands

```
check_xi_oraclequery 
check_xi_oracleserverspace 
check_xi_oracletablespace)
```

that are needed to monitor the Oracle DB (see pic. below).

[image]

How can I fix this?

TIA

Comment: for monitoring you can use zabbix,icinga.
https://www.nagios.com/solutions/oracle-monitoring/

Comment: @sanath - hi - I made some changes to the post. Can you look and comment?

Comment: yes those commands will show once you install oracle client, its mentioned here : https://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/Installing-Oracle-Plugins-in-Nagios-XI.pdf#_ga=2.113804677.306893599.1512364008-145864103.1512140331

Comment: @sanath - Part of this "solution" works with root - but - what is installed needs to also be accessible by the user "nagios" by setting 2 environment variables. There is one part (during nagios dockerfile setup) where the "nagios" user is created. How can I set the environment variables of the user "nagios" at the time of creation?

Comment: @sanath - I mentioned the use of the environment variables because - as mentioned above in the picture - the 3 commands (check_xi_oraclequery, 
check_xi_oracleserverspace, check_xi_oracletablespace) are not listed for configuration. The oracle client had been installed using the "root" user in the docker container. Thanks!

Comment: you installed oracle client using docker file mentioned here "https://github.com/sergeymakinen/docker-oracle-instant-client/blob/master/12.1/Dockerfile" or manual installation as root user? or take the docker nagios image and install oracle-client as nagios user for test

Comment: I took the "docker nagios image" and installed oracle client as "root" - it was not installed under the nagios id